# Django trans tag within a default filter

Tags: django, django-templates

Does anyone know how this could properly be written in Django?

```
{{ mu.expiry_date|default:"{% trans 'Free User' %}"}}
```

Obviously, the above does not work since it contains a tag within a tag's filter.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Templates have an [underscore syntax for translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#string-literals-passed-to-tags-and-filters) also:

```
{{ mu.expiry_date|default:_("Free User")}}
```